# Simple PDO brute force query not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to check attempted logins by the user has committed. For some reason it skips even tough I have 7 entries in my database, +1 of reach try, with similar IP and `user_id`.

This is my query, full code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/g4uPwLTG).

```
// BRUTE FORCE CHECK
$remote_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$sql = "
SELECT  attempt_nr 
FROM    users_login_attempts 
WHERE   user_id = :userid 
AND     time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
AND     user_ip = :userip
";

$results = $db_connect->prepare($sql);
if ($results->execute(array(':userid' => $user_id,':userip' => $remote_ip))){
    $count_tries = $results->rowCount();
    if ($count_tries < 5) {
        // DO SOMETHING IF LIMIT IS NOT REACHED
    }
    else { 
        // RETURN FAILURE 
    }
```

How come the user skips this part?

**IMAGES:
TABLE STRUCTURE**

[image]

**TABLE**

[image]

**MY CODE**

[image]

**THE VAR_DUMP RESULT**

[image]

Comment: have you echoed the query and tried to run directly in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: `time > NOW()` would imply a login time in the future, since the timestamp would have to be a greater value than the current time...

Comment: Its - 1 hour... Which means, get all the rows 1 hour back from NOW()

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I have Brute Force insert and password check AFTER this step. Works perfectly fine for valid input. Also adds an extra row when invalid input. So for some reason it skips the following query... Even tough It insert an exactly similar one afterwards.

Comment: have you looked at `timediff` and `timestampdiff` functions?

Comment: @RamRaider timediff wont help me, because I still need to use NOW minus 1 hour.

Comment: Sorry the screen cut off on my phone. `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` isn't valid but `DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR )` should work. Maybe try `> CURDATE()` and see what you get

Comment: @WebChemist No luck there. Still able to login even after 15 unsuccessful rows in database. See Update, tried in PHPMyAdmin, got a syntax error.

Comment: but you do get the expected results when you comment out the timestamp check right?

Comment: Comment out the timestamp? enlighten me...

Comment: @Gjert Ingar Gjersund - in that case you are not using it correctly - you can use it in this situation if needed

Comment: I'm confused with all your explanations. Don't you just mean that the `:userip` parameter is handled as number?

Comment: @RamRaider, could you provide a suggestion for that? I've tried to find solutions without using - 1 hour or now()

Comment: temporarily remove `AND     time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR` and verify you get results returned to make sure the problem isnt another part of the query.

Comment: @WebChemist Returns 0...

Comment: then if removing the timestamp check still doesn't yield results, the problem is something else. Edit the question and post your table structure or make a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @WebChemist Added images.

Comment: yeah that looks ok, other than I would change your ip column to `VARCHAR(15)` since an ipv4 address will never be more than 15 characters (ipv6 is still only 39 chars long).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [phpdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Note the suggestion against using `rowCount` for `select` queries.  Instead, I would change your code like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT  count(*) AS attempt_nr
FROM    users_login_attempts 
WHERE   user_id = :userid 
AND     time > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
AND     user_ip = :userip
";

$results = $db_connect->prepare($sql);
if ($results->execute(array(':userid' => $user_id,':userip' => $remote_ip))) {
    $row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count_tries = $row['attempt_nr'];
    if ($count_tries < 5) {
        // DO SOMETHING IF LIMIT IS NOT REACHED
    }
    else { 
        // RETURN FAILURE 
    }
}
```

In addition, note that with the code working correctly, you'll effectively lock your users out after 5 unsuccessful login attempts even if the user logged in successfully in between them, therefore you'll need to also ensure to clear the unsuccessful history on successful login or make your sql more complex to account for this.

Comment: @GjertIngarGjersund If this answer solved your problem then please kindly accept the answer.